# Adding new user with tableauserverclient (ParseError: mismatched tag)

Tags: python

I'm trying to add new user to the tableau server using tableauserverclient

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC # version 0.25

tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth('username', 'password', site_id='')
server = TSC.Server('url')
```

After my authentication (which is successful), I get this error (see below) after running this chunk of code

```
with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth): 
     newU = TSC.UserItem(user, 'Interactor')
     newU = server.users.add(newU) # error after this line of code
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\id\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

File "<ipython-input-20-97d94fcc47a2>", line 1, in <module>
    newU = server.users.add(newU)

File "C:\Users\id\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tableauserverclient\server\endpoint\endpoint.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\id\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tableauserverclient\server\endpoint\users_endpoint.py", line 79, in add
    new_user = UserItem.from_response(server_response.content, self.parent_srv.namespace).pop()

File "C:\Users\id\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tableauserverclient\models\user_item.py", line 211, in from_response
    return cls._parse_xml(element_name, resp, ns)

File "C:\Users\id\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tableauserverclient\models\user_item.py", line 221, in _parse_xml
    parsed_response = fromstring(resp)

File "C:\Users\id\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\defusedxml\common.py", line 126, in fromstring
    parser.feed(text)

File "C:\Users\id\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1632, in feed
    self._raiseerror(v)

File "C:\Users\id\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1531, in _raiseerror
    raise err

File "<string>", line unknown
ParseError: mismatched tag: line 218, column 12
```

It seems that is has something to do with the parsing procedure with the xml file,
I suppose that I should get access to this file and try to fix it.
I don't know where the file is located, is there any solution for this problem